# Is the Japanese Karaoke song list available on the UK version of the Wii U?

Tags: wii-u

My son got a Wii U from his Japanese Grandfather for Christmas the issue is that it's a Japanese Wii U and we live in the UK. We have a power transformer but we can't get any UK games and I can't read Japanese.

I was considering selling the Japanese version (because they go for a fair buck over here) and getting a UK equivalent. The only issue is that my wife would like the JP Karaoke.

I assume we have some sort of Karaoke available in the UK but are the Japanese songs available on that version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Karaoke game called [Karaoke Joysound](http://kjw.joysound.com/), but unfortunately the online services have been discontinued since 28 July this year. However, you'll still be able to play offline, but I'm not sure if you're able to download the songs if you haven't yet downloaded them.

Anyhow, there are quite many Japanese songs, based on this [google search of the monthly new songs list](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=wiiware%20karaoke%20joysound%20song%20list&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB1qS0_OnQAhUMm5QKHXKzDJEQ_AUICSgC&biw=1536&bih=758#imgrc=-2yNLWOEHnMKtM%3A). For an instance, [15/40 new songs added in May 2015](http://www.perfectly-nintendo.com/wii-karaoke-u-list-of-new-en-jp-songs-for-may-22nd-2015-europe/) were Japanese songs.